# Listen com port without blocking web application

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a web application with spring boot, i search a way to be able to have a method who always listening on the server com port, without blocking the rest of the application.

I use https://github.com/RishiGupta12/SerialPundit to read serial port.

Is there something special in spring to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is;

While your webapp is booting up;

- Spawn a thread that will listen on your serial port continously,
- Make it write it's output to a common place (i.e some thread-safe queue, ThreadLocal etc)
- Access to that common container from your Spring controllers

Have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html for detailed usage.

Comment: So I could run a  TaskExecutor. This task will do a blocking read. after reading, I need to call a rest service to do some validation.

Just don't really understand your second and third point.

Comment: @bernardderomme since TaskExecutor is on another thread it'll not block the whole web application, you can call your rest services while your serial port operations running. When it's done with serial port, it'll write to a commonly accessible medium.